# Android - Using same button over two activities

Tags: java, android, button, android-intent, android-activity

I have the following activity:

```
calc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String gpaString = gpa.getText().toString();
            if (gpaString.equals("")) {
                gpaString = "0";
            }
            double gpaDouble = Double.parseDouble(gpaString);

            String satString = sat.getText().toString();
            if (satString.equals("")) {
                satString = "0";
            }
            int satInt = Integer.parseInt(satString);

            String actString = act.getText().toString();
            if (actString.equals("")) {
                actString = "0";
            }
            int actInt = Integer.parseInt(actString);
            if (actInt / 36.0 < satInt / 2400.0) {
                scoreDouble = (0.6 * gpaDouble * 25)
                        + (0.4 * ((double) satInt / 2400.0) * 100.0);
            } else {
                scoreDouble = (0.6 * gpaDouble * 25)
                        + (0.4 * ((double) actInt / 36.0) * 100.0);
            }

            Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CollegeList.class);
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);



            }

        }
    );
```

In another activity I have the following code:

```
if(act/36.0>sat/2400.0){
        this.score = 0.6*gpa*25.0+0.4*(act/36.0)*100.0;
    }else{
        this.score = 0.6*gpa*25.0+0.4*(sat/2400.0)*100.0;
    }
    scoreDistance = Math.abs(this.score-MainActivity.scoreDouble)/MainActivity.scoreDouble;
    if(uagri&&ListOfMajors.agricultural||uchem&&ListOfMajors.chem){
        scoreDistance--;
    }else{
        scoreDistance = Math.abs(this.score-MainActivity.scoreDouble)/MainActivity.scoreDouble;
    }
}
```

How can I have the button from the first activity also perform the operations in the second activity? The variables used in the second activity are from objects in that activity so I cannot just copy that code into the first activity. Note that while variable names between the two activities may be named similarly, they are different variables.

Comment: you can try to implement an interface (http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html)

Comment: afford a hint, think best use for this fragment scenery, good practice!

Comment: @André.C.S I'm sorry, I don't quite get what you're saying

Comment: @RainbowJeremy, sorry for bad english! But i believe that to this scenario to use `Fragment` can be a best choose !

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can implement above functionality.

One is, by using "Intents". You can send data from one activity to another activity using intents.

Example, intent.putExtra("data", "data");

Second is, by creating separate class which will have static variables. So you can set values to those static variables & access those values.

Example, Global.variable = value; //Global is a class having static variable